# ARM Template, server name already exists but actually it didn't

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL Server using ARM Template.
While executing it, its throws an error of:

> Server Name already exists

but it does not.

I tried deploying it in many subscriptions and resource group of different regions but outcome is always same.

I'm calling resource group name as SQL Server name using **[resourceGroup().name]**.

Also, along with SQL Server, Vnet,Nsg,Local Network Gateway, VPN Gateway is deployed using resource group but are created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server name must be unique for all of Azure, not only within your subscription.

You get a fully qualified domain name for it, so you need a unique name:

```
yourservername.database.windows.net
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL server name should be universal unique not for your subscription